# ¿Por qué no se muestran datos en un dropdownlist de asp.net?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net, dropdownlist

Tengo un dropdown list de ASP.Net, intento llenarlo desde una llamada Ajax, entra el método de ASP.net, y en C# retorno la lista con la cual se llenará, pero cuando termino de debuggear el método, el dropdownlist sigue sin datos. Éste es mi código

```
    [WebMethod]

public static List<Lista> ListadoUsuariosAjax()
    {
        try
        {
            ///
            List<Lista> lstNombreLista = new List<Lista>();
            XmlSerializer xml_serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(cLogin));
            StringReader string_reader = new StringReader(CookieUtils.LeeValorCookie(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["nombreCookie"]));
            cLogin myLogin = (cLogin)xml_serializer.Deserialize(string_reader);
            ///
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            #region Cadena de Conexión
            SqlConnection miConexion = new SqlConnection(cadenaCon);
            #endregion
            if (miConexion.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                miConexion.Open();
            }
            using (SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("select Distinct NombreLista from ListaDestinatarios", miConexion))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comando);
                da.Fill(dt);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        lstNombreLista.Add(
                            new Lista
                            {
                                NombreLista = dt.Rows[i]["NombreLista"].ToString(),
                                NombreListaID = dt.Rows[i]["NombreLista"].ToString()
                            });
                    }

                }
                return lstNombreLista;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Ajax Call

```
        function GetDropDownData() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Formularios.aspx/ListadoUsuariosAjax",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#ddlUsers').empty();
                    $('#ddlUsers').append("<option value='0'>--Selecciona Lista--</option>");
                    $.each(result.d, function (key, value) {
                        debugger
                        $('#ddlUsers').append($("<option></option>").val(value.NombreLista).html(value.NombreListaID));
                    });
                },
                failure: function () {
                    alert("Failed!");
                }
            });
        }
```

DDList

```
<div>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUsers" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

Comment: Estás seguro que no arroja ninguna excepción?

Comment: @CrismanCarmona, No, no marca excepción, de hecho en el Result.d del Ajax, si vienen los elementos de la lista, pero éstos no se muestran en el DropDownList

Comment: Cual es el HTML final una vez que se ejecuta el metodo AJAX?

Comment: @AngelRuizC Parece que la solución era la falta del atributo "ClientIDMode="Static"
puesto que es un control de asp.net, lo demás funcionaba bien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que todo tu código está bien, excepto la forma en que llenas la lista desplegable con jQuery, la forma para llenar un `DrowDownList` es la siguiente:

```
$.each(result, function (i, value) {
    $("#ddlUsers").append('<option value="' + value.NombreListaID + '">' + value.NombreLista + '</option>');
});
```

Finalmente, tu código en la llamada Ajax quedará así:

```
function GetDropDownData() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Formularios.aspx/ListadoUsuariosAjax",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            $('#ddlUsers').empty();
            $('#ddlUsers').append("<option value='0'>--Selecciona Lista--</option>");
                $.each(result, function (i, value) {
                    $("#ddlUsers").append('<option value="' + value.NombreListaID + '">' + value.NombreLista + '</option>');
                });
        },
        failure: function () {
            alert("Failed!");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Cierto @Flxtr, olvidé también mencionar esa parte, corregí la manera de llenar el dropdownlist así cómo lo hiciste tú, y aparte agregue la propiedad "ClientIDMode="static" " al dropdownlist y ya funcionó perfecto

Answer (score 1):

La solución fue agregar el atributo "ClientIDMode="Static" al control de asp.net

Antes:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUsers" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ForeColor="Black">
</asp:DropDownList>

Después:

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUsers" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="form-control" ForeColor="Black">
</asp:DropDownList>
```